# How to get all the contents of specified class from string?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to make an app for windows phone for my forum.
Here is my function so far (just taking the xaml):

```
private async void go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient wc = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await wc.GetAsync("http://www.myforum.com/");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string xaml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        textXAML.Text = json;
    }
```

There are no errors in my code and I get the xaml.

What I want to do is get all the category names of the forum. All the category names have a class of "category-name".

How can I get the category names? Can I get them from a string? Do I have to parse the string or something?

Comment: Can you post the value of textXAML after you've sent your request?

Comment: It's really long and ugly so I'll just show you this part: 

    class=\"forumtitle\">Technology</a>

Comment: Side note: why would you use XAML to send data from server? Sending markup may make sense, but why would you need to parse on the client than?

Comment: Half line you've posted does not look like XAML at all... Are you sure you've posted correct value?

Comment: It's HTML. Sorry for the misnomer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this article on codeproject will help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/804660/How-to-Parse-Html-using-csharp

It uses a library called Htmlagilitypack which you can install via NuGet:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

The below example may work for your purposes but due to firewall issues I haven't been able to test it but hopefully it works and helps to answer your question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace HtmlParserDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        // Update the URL to the page you are trying to parse
        private const string Url = "http://www.bing.com/";
        private const string TagName = "a";
        private const string ClassName = "forumtitle";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting HTML from: {0}", Url);

                foreach (var category in GetCategories(Url, TagName, ClassName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(category);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                while (exception != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                    exception = exception.InnerException;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetCategories(string url, string htmlTag, string className = "")
        {
            var response = new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync(url).Result;
            string source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
            source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
            var result = new HtmlDocument();
            result.LoadHtml(source);

            return result.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(node =>  node.Name == htmlTag && 
                                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(className) || (node.Attributes["class"] != null &&
                                 node.Attributes["class"].Value == className)))
                .Select(node => node.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```